# Существует ли слово "клоунадство"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существует ли слово "клоунадство"?

Comment: https://keywordtool.io/ru/google: ищите и не найдёте.

Comment: Разве что в значении "строить из себя **клоуна ада**" - и то, если такое понятие было автором уже растолковано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет такого слова. Есть только ***клоунада***.

[Грамота:](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x)
**КЛОУНАДА**, -ы; ***ж.* 1.** Цирковой жанр - шуточные или сатирические сценки, разыгрываемые клоунами. **2.** Клоунская сценка; текст такой сценки.